# How to refresh entity instance with domain service?

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, domainservices

I use EF + domain service in SL app. In EF, entity update mapped to SP.
After entity data is saved to DB, I want entity is refreshed, so that those changes by SP can be brought back to entity in SL app.
How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this also related to domain services but in common EF with EDMX your SP must also have SELECT command to return refreshed data. Then in Stored procedure mapping you must map output parameters to entity properties.

Comment: In SP, I only return key as return.

Comment: Don't use RETURN and instead use SELECT to get all fields you want to refresh.